# Rounding numbers in my array of objects in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object

I have this object:

```
myObj = [
        {name: 'ice', price: 24.76834},
        {name: 'cake', price: 12.1623},
        {name: 'powder', price: 2}
      ];
```

I want to round the price element to two decimal places. I tried:

```
myObj.map(a => a.price.toFixed(2));
```

But it doesn't work! How can I round the price to two decimal places?

Comment: It is a good solution. Remember that the .map function returns fixed prices - this function doesn't change the source array. Maybe there's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let myObj=[
{name: 'ice', price: 24.76834},
{name: 'cake', price: 12.1623},
{name: 'powder', price: 2}
]

myObj = myObj.map(val => ({...val, price: val.price.toFixed(2)}));

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I'm wondering why my solution didn't work?

Comment: whatever you tried was correct. `map` will always return a new array and that you have to assign to your variable.

Comment: using map here is redundant, It works but if you are talking about performance and speed i don't think you should be using `map` at all

Answer (score 1):

```js
myObj=[
  {name: 'ice', price: 24.76834},
  {name: 'cake', price: 12.1623},
  {name: 'powder', price: 2}
]

myObj.forEach(val => {val.price = val.price.toFixed(2)})

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Hadn't noticed we placed the same answer at basically the same time...

Answer (score 1):

This job is perhaps better suited to [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
myObj = [{
    name: 'ice',
    price: 24.76834
  },
  {
    name: 'cake',
    price: 12.1623
  },
  {
    name: 'powder',
    price: 2
  }
]

myObj.forEach(a => a.price = a.price.toFixed(2));

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Totally agreed, Just a forEach is enough

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt work because you returning only the price instead of the whole object

```js
let myObj=[
{name: 'ice', price: 24.76834},
{name: 'cake', price: 12.1623},
{name: 'powder', price: 2}
]

let result = myObj.map(a => {
   a.price = a.price.toFixed(2);
   return a
})

console.log(result);
```

Also a little sidenote: The name `myObj` suggest me that this is an object witch isnt. An object is this `{}`

Comment: This Works ............... But don't you think you are using `result` without a reason, its more work than Just looping i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the spread operator.

```js
const myObj = [
  {name: 'ice', price: 24.76834},
  {name: 'cake', price: 12.1623},
  {name: 'powder', price: 2}
];

const result = myObj.map(a => ({
    ...a,
    price: a.price.toFixed(2)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
let myObj = [
          { name: "ice", price: 24.76834 },
          { name: "cake", price: 12.1623 },
          { name: "powder", price: 2 }
        ];
        var results = myObj.map((item) =>{ item.price.toFixed(2); return item;});
    
        console.log(results);
```